# Auditing outgoing transactions in Monero

Tags: viewkey, auditing

So I know that a view key is not suffice to audit outgoing transactions.
Still, can't a person re-sign his outgoing transactions and produce a valid ring signature with the same key image to an auditor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is called a SpendProofV1 and is implemented by the official Monero wallet. See this answer: [What is the "SpendProofV1..." or "OutProofV1..." in the details of a sent transaction in the GUI?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8122/what-is-the-spendproofv1-or-outproofv1-in-the-details-of-a-sent-transa)