# How can I use the SpendProofV1 to prove I sent Monero to an exchange?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mnemonic-seed

I've recovered an old wallet, where I previously Monero to an exchange from. How can I use the `SpendProofV1`, recovered from the `History` tab of the GUI, to prove I deposited Monero into their exchange?

Answer (score 3):

> The SpendProofV1 string contains a second, newly created ring
>   signature that proves exactly the same input ownership again, but
>   using different random initialization data. Only someone that owned
>   the inputs of the transaction would be able to create this second
>   valid ring signature. That is all the SpendProofV1 string contains.
>   There is no key derivation communicated, because it is unknown by the
>   wallet in this scenario.

(See [What is the "SpendProofV1..." or "OutProofV1..." in the details of a sent transaction in the GUI?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8122/what-is-the-spendproofv1-or-outproofv1-in-the-details-of-a-sent-transa))

Therefore you need to send both the transaction ID and the SpendProofV1 string. The exchange will be able to use this information to verify that you sent the funds.